# R interactive graph - remove a factor level\element and have axes adapt

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, interactive

I want to be able to present an interactive graph in R, which presents lines/bars/whatever of a measure grouped by a certain factor, and be able to make one or more of the factor's levels (groups) disappear AND have the x and y axes adapt to that, be responsive to this choice.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(factor1 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)),
             xAxisVar = c(1:7, 5, 9),
             yAxisVar = c(1:7, 5, 25))

ggplot(df, aes(xAxisVar, yAxisVar, group = factor1, color = factor1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

In this graph the y axis is extended to reach 25 because of 1 "large" observation in factor level "c". I want to be able to press on "c" or filter it out AND have the y axis respond to that, re-rendering the plot reaching 6 or so.

I have tried `plotly`'s `ggplotly`, you can automatically make group "c" disappear, but not have the plot re-rendering to account for that. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned `ggplotly`, so if you are open to `plotly`, you could try:

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

#from long to wide
df_wide <- dcast(df, xAxisVar ~ factor1, value.var="yAxisVar")

plot_ly(df_wide, x = ~xAxisVar, y = ~a, name='a', type='scatter', mode='lines+markers')  %>%
  add_trace(y = ~b, name = 'b', type='scatter', mode='lines+markers') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~c, name = 'c', type='scatter', mode='lines+markers', connectgaps = TRUE) %>%
layout(
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      type = "buttons",
      x = -0.1,
      y = 0.7,
      label = 'Category',
      buttons = list(
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list('visible', c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
             label = "a"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list('visible', c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
             label = "b"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list('visible', c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
             label = "c")
      )
    )))
```